# AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

Unable to Get the Access token , Grant Type: password

URL :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token?resources=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F
```

Request:

```
  {'grant_type': 'password', 'client_id': <client_id>, 'scope': 'openid User.Read Mail.Read', 'username': '<email_id>', 'client_secret': '<client_secret>, 'password':<password>}
```

Response:

```
    {'correlation_id': 'bbe33e96-aeb8-4e8f-8a2f-1330510c298f', 
     'error_codes': [70002, 50126],
     'timestamp': '2018-12-19 06:58:03Z',
     'error': 'invalid_grant',
     'trace_id': 'c69686fb-a84e-4299-a72c-0cf079381300', 
     'error_description': 'AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password\r\nTrace ID: c69686fb-a84e-4299-a72c-0cf079381300\r\nCorrelation ID: bbe33e96-aeb8-4e8f-8a2f-1330510c298f\r\nTimestamp: 2018-12-19 06:58:03Z'}
```

Can any one find out whats going wrong.
User name and password are correct.

Comment: Could be an encoding problem. The body needs to be URL-encoded. Usually if you use the framework-provided tools for constructing the body it does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you try the following way:

URL:

```
Post https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Content-Type:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Request body:

```
client_id=<client_id>&
scope=https://graph.microsot.com/Mail.Read openid User.Read&
grant_type=password&
username=<email_id>&
client_secret=<client_secret>&
password=<password>
```

And the response:
[image]

Comment: @Gaurav Modi, I already update the new answer. If there is anything not clear, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't that be graph.microsoFt.com?

Answer (score -1):

For me the below worked out in Postman.

URL(POST) :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Header:

```
Content-Type 
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Request Body(text):

```
client_id=<client_id>&
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&
grant_type=client_credentials&
client_secret=<client_secret>
```

Comment: Here you are using grant_type=client_credentials, it will surely give you error with grant_type=password

Comment: @shobhit-walia, I didnt say it will work for grant_type=password.I simply gave a solution to get access token, what worked for me, i suggested that resolution. Can you please take out the down vote.

Comment: Hi @Arpita, yes you are right, your solution will work but not in above scenario, because here, grant_type=password is explicitly mention in the given question.